# How to use utf8 characters as key of object

Tags: python

That's what I want:

```
data = {}
a = 'имя'
b = 'фамилия'
data[a] = 'osman'
data[b] = 'omar'
```

`encode('utf-8')` and `decode('utf-8')` doesn't work. How can I achieve such result?

Comment: Your code runs fine for me in both Python 2 (with an encoding declaration added) and Python 3.  What Python version are you using, and what error are you getting?

Comment: Running this code doesn't seem to give any errors, what's the output you're expecting?

Comment: That's not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this line on top of your .py file if you are using Python2:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

If you are using Python3 your code works just fine.